# syntax error at end of input in PostgreSQL when use INNER JOIN LATERAL

Tags: postgresql

I tried to merge a quarterly table and a monthly table by using INNER JOIN LATERAL, but encountered error.
[state_smm table, monthly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZRAm.png)
[unemp table, quarterly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14FDj.png)

my code is:

```
SELECT st.state,
    st.monthly_reporting_period AS month,
    st.CPR,
    up.unemp_rate AS Most_Recent_Quarterly_unemp
FROM state_smm AS st
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
    -- Find the value for latest quarter that ended on or before the monthly date
    SELECT unemp.unemp_rate
    FROM unemp
    WHERE unemp.state = st.property_state
        AND unemp.quarter <= st.monthly_reporting_period
    ORDER BY unemp.quarter DESC
    limit 1
)AS up
```

and I got error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 14: )AS up
               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 434
```

How can I edit my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A `JOIN` needs a join condition - you are missing the `ON` part

Comment: I got it, thanks! just put `ON true` in the end, and it works.

Comment: If it works it does not mean it is correct. ON true leads to returning of cartesian product which in 99% of cases is wrong even if the query executes.

Comment: @armagedescu thanks! What do you think to add on the `ON` part? I am trying to merging quarterly data with monthly data. how to write the code?

Comment: @JingsiXu it should be a condition identically as where, but matching the relation between the two tables like ON table1.colA=table2.colB. Usually it matches the primary and foreign key.

Comment: @armagedescu this is not correct for LATERAL joins. A lateral join is essentially joining with the result of a subquery that's executed once per row of the outer result. It's an alternative to executing the subquery in a loop. Long story short, the ON clause is only necessary to satisfy the compiler. You usually want to use `ON true` for lateral joins.